# SSH login fails in one of the cluster node when login with user authenticated by a LDAP server

Tags: linux, ssh, ldap

I am not able to login from one server to another node but not vice-versa (let's say from **B** --> **A** SSH login works but **A** --> **B** login fails). The user is authenticated via remote *LDAP* server and **sssd** configuration `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` is properly done to access LDAP. *Passwordless* SSH connectivity is setup between both the servers.

These are the following observations:

- **ldapsearch** for that user returns result from both the servers and ldap server is reachable
- no **AllowUsers** or deny parameter in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file in both the servers
- **sss** method is configured properly for **password**, **shadow**, and **group** in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
- tried login after stopping the **iptables** service in the problematic server rules out the possibility of firewall rule's involvement in blocking this
- *SELinux* status is disabled, so it has no role to play here
- **pam_ldap.so** PAM rule is not found in the files under `/etc/pam.d` directory in both the servers

Still not able to figure out the reason for the connectivity failure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed by doing the following:

added this line `ldap_tls_reqcert=allow` to the end of `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`
and copied `/root/LDAP/ca.crt`  from ldap server to the particular problematic node's `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/ca.crt`
and restarted the **sssd** service, `service restart sssd`